# Is there a better way of creating this case query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a case subquery that does work, however I am sure there must be an easier way of doing this?

The aim of the query is when billgrp_desc like '30%', then display billgrp_desc from tbm.billgrp table.

Otherwise display matter_code from hbm.matter table when billgrp_desc not like '30%'

The query is below:

```
select 
 case
    when bllgrp_desc like '30%' then 'billgrp_desc'
 end
from tbm.billgrp
union 
select 
 case
    when exists (select billgrp_desc
                 from tbm.billgrp
                 where billgrp_desc not like '30%') then 'matter_code'
  end
from hbm.matter
```

Comment: Is this only a part of a larger query? If yes, it's better you supply the full query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I am assuming Matter_code is a field from the matter table

```
select 
    case
        when bllgrp_desc like '30%' then billgrp_desc
     end
from tbm.billgrp
union 
    select 
           isNull(gp.billgrp_desc,mt.matter_code)
    from hbm.matter mt
    left join billgrp gp on billgrp_desc not like '30%'
```

Comment: Based on the fact that he says his current method works, I'd guess that he actually wants to select the value `billgrp_desc` rather than the column value.

Comment: Maybe, don't really know from the question...   You are right though, if he is only selecting the literal string, he doesn't need the matter table.   I think he is selecting the literal string for test purposes, and once he gets the right result, he will replace them with field names.

Comment: Hi all, the main aim of this query is to validate that when billgrp_desc has prefix of 30.... use billgrp_desc. Otherwise when billgrp_desc does not have a prefix of 30... use matter_code from the hbm.matter table. Although your query does work sparky it takes a long time to run, in fact it is over 3 mins and still running. My query is not pretty, returns the resultset in 5 secs

Comment: How big are the tables?   Is the billgrp table indexed on billgrp_desc?

Comment: tables are quite large = 136596 rows. billgrp_desc is not indexed

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go this route:

```
select 
 case
    when bllgrp_desc like '30%' then 'billgrp_desc'
    else 'matter_code'
 end
from tbm.billgrp
```

Since you are not selecting anything from the `matter` table I don't see a reason to query it...  The is also no reason to union that I can see.  Just select all the rows you want the first time.